# Why my OpenShift build across different projects builds ok, but the verification throws an exception?

Tags: jenkins, openshift, jenkins-pipeline

In OpenShift, I have a Jenkins instance running on a project (my-jenkins-project) and I have a build (my-openshift-build) in a different project (my-test-project), which that builds but the verification fails. The build works, but the verification fails. Why?

Jenkins file
     sh "oc start-build  my-openshift-build --from-file=target/my-openshift-build.jar -n my-test-project"
        openshiftVerifyBuild apiURL: '', authToken: '', bldCfg: 'my-openshift-build ', checkForTriggeredDeployments: 'false', namespace: '', verbose: 'false', waitTime: '40', waitUnit: 'min'

```
Starting the "Verify OpenShift Build" step with build config "my-openshift-build" from the project "my-jenkins-project".
Waiting on build "null" to complete ...
Operation will timeout after 2400000 milliseconds 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.openshift.internal.restclient.model.List cannot be cast to com.openshift.restclient.model.IBuild
```

Answer (score 0):

In non-cross projects Jenkins instance - build, you do not have to set the namespace parameter in the openshiftVerifyBuild , but in this case the Jenkins pipeline, you do.

Just add the target namespace in the openshiftVerifyBuild step and it works, in this case:

```
    openshiftVerifyBuild apiURL: '', authToken: '', bldCfg: 'my-openshift-build ', checkForTriggeredDeployments: 'false', namespace: 'my-test-project', verbose: 'false', waitTime: '40', waitUnit: 'min'
```